# Do I need to remake jar file every time I update config file?

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, jakarta-mail, config

I have a config.properties file that my JavaMail program pulls from for the email address's, message, etc. When I update the config.properties file, the jar file doesn't pull from that config file, but instead pulls from the config file when I initially created the jar file. I am using Eclipse. I was wondering if there's a way to make the jar file pull from the updated config file or if I had to remake the jar every time. Thanks.

Comment: If you read a resource in a jar through a classloader the classloader will usually cache the resource.

Answer (score 0):

the answer is **yes** you have to rebuild everytime if you want to pull from the `classpath` ( inside a `.jar` ).

don't put the file in the `.jar` is always an option

Comment: Is there another option?

Comment: put the properties file on filesystem and add its directory to your classpath while running it